# Ordering $file by name - Smart templates

Tags: smarty

I wonder if anyone can help me. I'm using PodHawk - a basic podcast cms, I would like the admin area file select to show my files in order - by name.

The select/option dropdown uses this code, is there a straightforward way to get the dropdown to display in order by name,. I've searched but cant find anything in the Smarty documentation, but I'm probably using the wrong terminology!

```
{foreach from=$upload item=file}
    <option value="{$file|escape:'url'}">{$file}</option>
{/foreach}
```

many thanks rob

Solved with many thanks to poster below -

```
{$upload|@sort:$smarty.const.SORT_NUMERIC} 
{foreach from=$upload item=file}
    <option value="{$file|escape:'url'}">{$file}</option>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: mind marking this question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cgwyllie neglected that asort() returns a boolean, not the sorted array. So his approach wouldn't work. As the index is not used, a(ssociative)sort is not required.

```
{$_foo = $upload|sort:$smarty.const.SORT_LOCALE_STRING}
{foreach $upload as $file}
  <option value="{$file|escape:'url'}">{$file|escape:"html"}</option>
{/foreach}
```

should do the trick. Make sure you really need that $file urlencoded, otherwise change escape:"url" to escape:"html".

(the above is Smarty3 syntax)

Comment: while at it, your solution {$upload|@sort} should output "1", as sort returns a boolean true, if sorting was successufl and true casted to string is "1". either assign the result to a variable you're not using, or wrap the sorting call in a {capture} block.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `$upload` contains an array of file names, then it should be possible to apply the PHP `asort` function (http://php.net/asort) to the array as a smarty modifier.

```
{foreach from=$upload|@asort item=file}
    <option value="{$file|escape:'url'}">{$file}</option>
{/foreach}
```

The @ symbol is needed to apply the modifier to the array as a whole, and not to each individual element. (See http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl)

If the array is of more complex data structures than just strings, the following discussion may be of use to you: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1079&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

**Edit**

As mentioned by rodneyrehm, this solution is not quite correct although the poster found a satisfactory solution at: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1079&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

Comment: Hello cgwyllie, thankyou for the links, must admit little out of my depth. Looking at the second link (forum post) this seemed to make the most sense and worked perfectly for my needs. Many thanks {$upload|@sort:$smarty.const.SORT_NUMERIC}

Comment: @RobOliver glad to hear that you've found a solution!